# M4 sees end of file in string

Tags: m4

I'm getting a m4-parsing error that it sees an EOF character in the 2nd line of the following set of lines (which will be executed in a seperate shell:

```
     "set V1 = `grep -c  'z = 10\.0e-6'     qt_data/kxfo_ssr_udfo_tmp/* | wc -l`;\
      set V2 = `grep -c  'z = -30\.0e-6'    qt_data/kxfo_ssr_udfo_tmp/* | wc -l`;\
      test $V1 > 0;\
      test $V1 = $V2 "
```

The error I get is: `<path-to-file>:<line>:ERROR: end of file in string`

(For clarity: the line that gives the issue is: `` set V2 = `grep -c  'z = -30\.0e-6'    qt_data/kxfo_ssr_udfo_tmp/* | wc -l`;\ ``)

I'm trying to find out which of the character combinations is seen by M4 and how to escape that as EOF since the command in itself works without problems in a shell.

Does anybody know how I can fix the error since I cannot find the character-combi that is seen as EOF by M4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not ideal although workable solution might be to use the `changequote` built-in macro:

1. Choose an non-existent character to be considered as a start quote and an end character to be considered as an end quote. For instance: `changequote("""", """)`; here, you are saying to the m4 interpreter that `""""` is a start quote and `"""` is an end quote from now on until the interpreter finds the macro `changequote()`.
2. To reverse this behavior (meaning, go back to the standard definition of quotes from the point you do not wish this assumption anymore), you need to use the built-in macro `changequote()` without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The grave accent and the accute accent are the left and right quoting strings, by default. This prevents the recognization of special characters. It is also treated as a single token (a quoted string) and its value is the text between the quotes with one level of quotes stripped off.

The quote characters can be nested but they must be balanced.

```
 $ m4 test.m4
 define(`foo', `This is macro `foo'.')dnl
 foo
 => This is macro foo.
```

In your case, the backquote is not the M4 left quoting string but a character that must be interpreted specially by the shell (command substitution). In other words, the default left quoting string interferes with the final text.

```
changequote(`[',`]')dnl
nb_files=`find . -type f | wc -l`; echo $nb_files
changequote`'dnl
```

**Note:** You should use `changequote` to restaure the default quoting strings because `changequote()` is unspecified (c.f. POSIX specification).

**Note:** You should be careful when you change the quoting strings (e.g. see below).

```
$ m4 test2.m4
divert(`-1')
changequote(`[',`]')
define([foo], [syscmd(false)ifelse(sysval,[0],,
                                  [m4exit([1])])])
changequote
divert`'dnl
foo
error-> m4:foo.m4:7: non-numeric argument to builtin `m4exit'
```